# How to apply for a Schengen visa when not having a specific plan in advance?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, indian-citizens

I am planning a trip across Europe but I'm a bit sketchy on the details and would really appreciate some help with the following questions:

1) I have a temporary UK residency since I'm a student there and intend on applying at the French Embassy in the UK, however I will be travelling with my folks who will be applying from a different country since they don't live in the UK, would that be a problem?

2) My plans are very sketchy at the moment so I'm thinking of making a spoof booking for flights and hotels.  The plan is to go to France and then Switzerland and Italy but would it be enough to provide only partial info -- I.e.,  make it appear that I'm just travelling to France as I want to apply as soon as possible and just so I don't have to make other bookings hastily now?

Comment: What citizenship do you hold? What citizenship do your parents hold?

Comment: Personally, while it easy to create changeable hotel bookings, I have found it hard to make cancellable bookings for the travel part. So, you need to pin down your travel a fair bit, which makes it worthwhile to just figure out your whole trip before getting into the visa application.

Comment: France does asks for an itinerary, so might be an issue if somebody decides to investigate. Most of the time(inside France if travelling by train) they check your passport and visa and let you go. In the airports they will ask questions(atleast the Finns do so).

Comment: I hold an Indian citizenship. I really need to know if my family and I need to apply together or can we apply from two different countries? And do I need to show their reservations as well as mine even if I'm making an application in a separate embassy given that I state I'm travelling with them?

Answer (score 1):

Your only solution for traveling with no specific plans is as follows:

1) Apply for your first **single-entry** Schengen visa with an exact itinerary

2) When the first visa expires, apply for a second **multi-entry** visa with an exact itinerary

3) Once you've traveled once on your multi-entry visa following the itinerary submitted to the embassy, it's perfectly legal to enter the Schengen area at any airport without having an exact plan until the last minute.